# I need to return the user tag on the discord and he will be mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.tag

message.channel.send(`${member}`)}
```

The value of `member` is `undefined`. I need the tag of a person mentioned, e.g: `user # 111`.

Answer (score 2):

[`MessageMentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) is a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) and it has no `tag` property. Neither does a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

You'll have to get the first [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) in the [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) and then get its tag.

---

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
message.channel.send(member.user.tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `message.mentions.members.first()`:

```js
let user = message.mentions.members.first().user;
message.reply(user.tag);
```